# Urllib2.urlopen doesn't connect to server

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to generate high bandwidth on a server, by calling images from facebooks note feature but the request fails each time giving the following information

"Content-Type: image/gif
Pragma: no-cache
X-FB-Debug: GQ3jId2Ww4kTzNXABjwM878C5CAOMIcBxK716TKwPd1/cQeHIqAwVLnLWFMAZkcxTdgM2KecO67q+H8xnEDg==
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 43
Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=529
Expires: Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:50:27 GMT
Date: Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:41:38 GMT
Connection: close "

```
for u in urls :
    try :
        urllib2.urlopen(u)
        print (urllib2.urlopen(u).info())
    except urllib2.HTTPError , err :
        if err.code == 404 :
            print "[!] 404 Page not found !"
            exit()
        else :  
            print "[!] HTTP Error !"    
    except :
        print "[!] Connect Error !"
```

Where

```
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://
(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|
[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', read_note_message)
```

I have tried adding in the user_agent header to see if Facebook doesn't allow a connection from a python user agent but that just causes a connection error. Is there something wrong with the url that is being called? As the note is created by the code so it is connecting to facebook without a problem.

Comment: What you're getting is a successful response. Why do you think it's failing?

Comment: There is no bandwidth generated on the server and no packets picked up in wireshark, I just assumed that it would that part of the code failing as all the rest is working. Plus my supervisor for the project said that it was that part I had to fix but I just couldn't get it to work

Comment: Also when urlilb2.urlopen(u).read() is printed there is a connection error

Comment: You have an `except:` block. What's the actual error?

Comment: The url generated is incorrect as far as I can tell so it seems the code is working but the "urls" used are not. The except block that is there is the only error message that occurs. I am pretty lost here, I have only been learning python for a few weeks so if I am way off I apologise but all I know is that this is the part that is meant to read the note in the simulated browser and it generates no bandwidth but just opening the note in a real browser does. Is there something I can do to give you better information?

Comment: Your last `except` block catches *all* errors, throws out all of the information they hold, and just says, "there's an error". Get rid of the outer `try: ... except: ...` block and figure out what the actual error is. As far as Facebook is concerned, it probably relies heavily on JavaScript to load all of the components of the website, so your script that just sends a single HTTP request isn't enough.

Comment: Could this be cause by the encoding of the charset? say if I set it to utf-8 would that make any difference

Comment: I have finally got it to not show any errors with using the charset utf-8 but it is still not generating any bandwidth on my server, apparently [link]fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php[link] sometimes won't load a full size image, is that something wrong with the code or is it something else and the code is fine?

Comment: Oh and the code will send out 1000's of requests if that fixes what you said about only one request being sent?

Comment: I have debugged the link generated and found that the error, even when it says that it is running fine is "Can't Download Could not retrieve data from URL." and "Response Code 206", I'm not sure what is happening when it seems to be working but it is obviously not